# Magento 2: Add child div containing all items in columns

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.2.5, page, reference

Below is my html struture of 2-column layout,

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column main">
        ------
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
        ------
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to add add child div to colum that contains all items in it , my new struture to be like

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="newcolumns">
        <div class="column main">
            ------
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
            ------
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried below code but it does not work

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="newcontinaer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="newcolumns" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Based on one answer in stackexchange i tried below, but is is not as expected

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
    <container name="columns.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main" before="-" />
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="newcolumns" />
<move element="main" destination="columns" />
```

how to fix it

---

AFter suggestion from **Sukumar Gorai** i created 2columns-left.xml and it works fine , but instead i want to create new layout teamplate and assign same to my category i tried as below but it does not works

my html structure after this was like

```
<div class="columns">
    <div class="newcolumns">
        <div class="column main">
            <div class="block filter">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
            Blank sidebar filter moved to column main
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">

    <layout id="2columns-left-product">
        <label translate="true">MY Product</label>
    </layout>

</page_layouts>
```

**2columns-left-product.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="newcontainer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="newcolumns">
            <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
                <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
            </container>
            <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
                <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="main" destination="newcontainer" before="-" />
</layout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file named **2columns-left.xml** in your theme under below path:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

and use the below content for **2columns-left.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="newcontainer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="newcolumns">
            <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" after="main">
                <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
            </container>
            <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
                <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="main" destination="newcontainer" before="-" />
</layout>
```

Flush the cache and test.

Comment: it tried it add div beore side bar not like what i want can u please help

Comment: thanks it is working , one issue can i change order i means first sidebar then column main

<div class="newcolumns">
        
        <div class="sidebar sidebar-main">
            ------
        </div>
<div class="column main">
            ------
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: If it's working fine for you then accept the answer so that it will help others in future.

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can change the order.

Comment: Hi it works when i create "2columns-left.xml"  i tried creating new layout and assigning my catlog category that layout in that case sidebar thing is blank and is rendered inside column main how to fix that

Comment: can you help with that custom layout assign thing

Comment: Can you update your page_layout file to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83930/discussion-between-user1799722-and-sukumar-gorai).